# Possible to achieve Google Maps Location as an independent programmer

Tags: android, google-maps

To better elaborate with this question, I have spent weeks "sharpening" the user's location in my app using the methods and strategies on Google Docs yet none have gotten me to where I wanted. I look at Google Maps for Android and see that their interface and location tracking is highly accurate and stable but I have not found anywhere any open source library or app that has even remotely gotten close to what Google has on their Maps app. So even if it is Yes or No, my question is; is it possible to achieve that accuracy and stability in my app or does google save the best for themselves? If so can anyone point me to any documentations or sources that would help me get closer to that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, you just have to pay for the privilege.

Google itself pays a third party for having that extra accuracy. The licensing agreement it has with that third party doesn't allow it to share that information with third party developers.

Hold on. I'm going to look up a source for what I'm saying. I'll be back shortly.

Comment: Thanks, a source would be great. As i would be willing to pay for that accuracy if that is the case.